# Find adjacent numbers in an random number array using python

Tags: python, arrays, recursion, numbers

I have an array with `x = [1,9,7,6,8,4,8,3,4,2]` i want to display only 3 adjacent numbers. So my answer should be `[1,2,3]`.

Comment: What have you tried so far in order to achieve what you *want*?

Comment: What about `[6, 7, 8]`?

Comment: @schwobaseggl bro first adjacent numbers... but how you will do this ?

Comment: @DirtyBit bro i tried all possible solutions which came to my mind. but didn't able to find anything

Answer (score 0):

I cant understand your question properly but think this is what you are looking for.

```
import numpy as np
x = [1,9,7,6,8,4,8,3,4,2]
x=np.sort(x)
print x[0:3]
```